# how to differentiate templates based on cases

Tags: xslt

Hi i've the below two cases in XML.

**Case1:**

```
<para num="01"><page num="05"/>abcdefghij ancfrgthig</para>
```

**Case2:**

```
<para num="01">abcdefgrghy sdfdfhrtfd<page num="05"/></para>
```

**Case3:**

```
<para num="01"><span class="bold">abcdefgrghy sdfdfhrtfd</span><page num="05"/></para>
```

**Case4:**

```
<para num="01"><span class="bold">abcdefgrghy</span><page num="05"/> sdfdfhrtfd</para>
```

**Case5:**

```
<para num="01"><span class="bold">abcdefgrghy</span> sdfdfhrtfd<page num="05"/> </para>
```

**Case5:**

```
<para num="01"><span class="bold">abcdefgrghy sdfdfhrtfd</span><page num="05"/> </para>
```

I need to differentiate these two cases, because i want to make different templates for each.

I use directly `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, but here if i have the first case stated above, first the page template needs to be called by the para template.

Thanks

Comment: The first sample is not even well-formed, an end tag `</page>` is missing.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen, sorry, i've edited it now.

Comment: If those two cases actually represent your scenario (no text after or before a certain child element), you can use `//para/page[following-sibling::text()]` to select the first one and `//para/page[preceding-sibling::text()]` to find the second one.

Comment: This assumes your cases are only those two: when there is text following the tag, and when there is text preceding the tag. Those expressions will not match tags with *no text* following or preceding, however, and will always match if there is text before *and* after.

Comment: You can also use modes `<xsl:template ... mode="...">` and `<xsl:apply-templates ... mode="...">` to apply different templates on `<para>` for each different situation.

Comment: Hi @helderdarocha, thanks for the solutuion, just to be more precise, does the first solution act same on the remaining cases i've added just now. Thanks again

Comment: Are you still considering 2 cases (with five different examples)? Or five cases? Which examples belong to each case?

Comment: here I've created total 5 cases while going through my XML, i found that there were some more tags between the para and page, so i made it a new case. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52215/discussion-between-user2423959-and-helderdarocha)

Comment: Instead of adding more and more examples (six by now), why don't you spend a moment and write out the logic **in words**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your valuable comments, I've fixed my issue and below is the solution.

```
<xsl:choose>

  <xsl:when test="child::node()[1][self::*]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="child::page[1]"/>
    <div class="para">
      <xsl:call-template name="phrase"/>    
      <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::page)]"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:when>  

  <xsl:otherwise>
    <div class="para">
      <xsl:call-template name="phrase"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
  </xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>
```

Thanks again!